# why would you use Func<string> instead of just string?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**Why would you use**`Func<string>` **instead of just** `string` ?

My question is specifically in regards to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/durablefunctions-apiscraping-dotnet/blob/master/FanOutFanInCrawler/Orchestrator.cs) repo.

The line in question is 22:

```
    private static Func<string> getToken = () => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GitHubToken", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

`getToken` encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a `string`. **What is the reason for not simply typing this variable to be a string?**

**Why would you use**`Func<string>` **instead of just** `string` ?

Comment: *Why would you useFunc<string> instead of just string?* opinion-based ... go ask the author why he used

Comment: Not opinion based  at all - **in a container environment, which all serverless apps are**, the easiest way to propagate configuration is through environment variables. Which can obviously change.

Comment: @Selvin not opinion based - in container environments, environment variables are the preferred configuration method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the linked code both the `Func<string>` and its use are in `private static` fields - it should not make a difference here, should it? As I understand it, in this specific case, the function will only be called once (per context).

Comment: Can't post answer any more. Here my opinion, With being this field `private static` possibly designed to lazy load the token. Also the other argument `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` explains it as well that it might change based on associated process.

Comment: Why I would use `Func<string>` instead of just `string` is opinion. Why the designers of Azure Functions require a `Func<T>` is a different question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, it's not just opinion. There's a clear reason why it would be done. It's not just semantics.

Comment: @mason The reason I program anything in any way is that in my opinion, it's the best way to program it. Are you telling me that I program something because of some other reason?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not opinion, it's a common pattern in containers. It's probably the *easiest* way to distribute configuration to multiple container instances running on multiple hosts, without the applications inside the container having to do anything.

Comment: Come down guys. We may be able to answer the question within the specific scope of the code above, which seemks to be some container-thing. However the question is posted in a way that makes me assume to be of a much more general scope then the above mentioned. In thise case it´s impossible to give a decent answer that covers them all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You might be right but the OP said: "My question is _specifically_ in regards to this repo".

Comment: The delegate gets invoked right away in the next declaration.  So no, there is no point in avoiding a string.  It is not a great practice, especially so for config code, this programmer is not used to having to debug his code.

Comment: @Selvin Wouldn't you know, the author of the code replied 

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, I would, thanx for ping

Answer (score 5):

I can see five reasons one might do this:

1. When you want to allow for a value that will not only change over time (you could still accomplish that with a property!), but the place you need to check to find it might change. For example, by default you check an environment variable, but there's a user option somewhere that will instead look in a config file, or a web service, or database table, etc. Now you can swap out the function call, rather than checking that config option every time inside a function that must know how to do all of those.
2. It makes it just very slightly easier to use this in an `async` context, where you can await the results. You can await the function in a task directly, rather than having to also wrap the property as an awaitable method.
3. They wanted function semantics rather than property semantics. This is a choice, where they wanted to present a function call as the public API for the type instead of a property. The lambda, then, (really: [expression bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)) is just a shorter way to write the method.
4. This was written before the new [default interface implementations in C# 8](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/default-implementations-in-interfaces-in-c-sharp-8/), where the code is providing a default implementation, but really expects you to "override" it and replace the method with your own that can look at whatever value you need. Or, even if they were using C# 8, an additional interface was seen as not worth the effort.
5. It's easier to change out the implementation in dependancy injection scenarios, though hopefully someone doing that *would* be using an interface instead. Typically you inject the whole type, rather than a single method.

Comment: DIMs for this ...hmmmm. That's a *nice* trait. It should probably be added as an example to the DIM tag

Answer (score 2):

By storing it as a `Func<string>`, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` will be called each time the variable is accessed. Meaning if `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` would return a different value on subsequent calls, you'll get the new value.

As far as I can tell, the only way `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` will return a different value for the same input is if [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_) is called.

Comment: The question is about Azure Functions, a container-based environment, with multiple instances running on multiple hosts. Using env variables is perhaps the most common way to distribute configuration

Comment: actually this is the only way to say why it's a `Func<string>` ... that the host of azure function using 1) same process and 2) `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` in other case simple `static string envvar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GitHubToken");` whould be enough

Comment: You could also put the code to check the environment variable in a property getter, no `Func<string>` needed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, you could. However, I tend to not put stuff that might throw an exception into properties. `GetEnvironmentVariable ` can throw a SecurityException according to the documentation. Probably unlikely, so the difference is pretty small in this case.

Comment: You are right. I limited the repository to an environment variable to limit the number of Azure services I was using. Replace this with Azure KeyVault and things may be different. Think of API key changing and someone just updating keyvault.

Answer (score 2):

Author of the repository here.

The main reason this was used is that the class is static and the property is static. Although the environment variable may change, it will not get reflected until the actual application is rebooted.

The main reason I did it is that it should never be in an environment variable. It should be saved in secret service storage like Azure KeyVault (AWS HSM?). That value may change without notice, without rebooting the application, and would continue using the old token until an error happens.

What would need to be done in that scenario is purely replace the implementing function by one that will correctly secure your data.

Comment: You say "the environment variable may change but won't get reflected until the application is rebooted" - are you sure about that? If someone calls Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable then the value will change (as the application sees it) even if the process isn't restarted, [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: @maxime, how did you find this post?

Comment: @mason The thing is the environment variable may change due to external reasons excluding .NET runtime. Setting the variable through the portal, etc. 99% of time, static variable is fine. If you want to cover key expiration and replacement, you need something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' https://twitter.com/pkanavos/status/1204794336820580353

Comment: So #4 from my answer, then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would use a `Func<T>` instead of `T` if the value that your function produces could change during the execution of your program.

It is also useful for DI scenarios, where the consumer of the function doesn't care (or shouldn't know, ...) where the value is coming from. It just needs to be able to produce the currently correct one.

That doesn't seem to be the case in your example, though. There, you could just have a `private static string token = ...` with the same result.

Comment: This ignores the scenario where the value coming from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable changes, which is probably why it wasn't hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Using environment variables for configuration is a common pattern in container environments. Those variables are expected to change, so using a `Func<string>` to pull the latest variable makes sense. The container itself doesn't need to know anything about the configuration store, or how the changes are made or propagated.

The changes are propagated by the orchestrator or host, to all containers that need that particular setting. This would allow different groups of containers to work using different settings, to serve different tenants or .... work with different Github accounts perhaps?

The container apps though remain oblivious to all this.

AWS Lambda and Azure Functions are based on containers, so this pattern makes sense.

**Why Func instead of a string Property?**

That's slightly opinion based. If one prefers functional programming, passing and injecting single-purpose functions is better than passing around objects with a single property or worse, multiple possibly unrelated properties.

Comment: Meh. You could still do this with a property.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the question was why a `Func<string>` instead of a static `string`. Not how to access the env variable. I'd guess the author prefers functional programming. A single *function* is far easier to inject than an object+properties too

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it is trying to communicate intent.

When executing a method you're more aware that there is the potential for an error to be thrown or that there is something that can be done to change the value, which in this case is the environment configuration.